# LaTeX3 - Using .tl_set:N with .code:n

Tags: latex3

I am trying to create a single key to use for multiple purposes.

I have an `assignment` key that accepts some value which is stored in  `\ l__aljumaily_componentNumber_tl`. In addition to this, it should also store some text in `\l__aljumaily_componentType_tl`. I have another key `lecture` that also stores the component type using `\l__aljumaily_componentNumber_tl` (similar to `assignment`) but now stores something else in `\l__aljumaily_componentType_tl`.

To store the component type, I used `.code:n = { ... }`. Now, storing the component number works correctly *without* the usage of `.code:n = { ... }`, otherwise, it will only register the initial value of the component number. How can I use a single key to take care of the component type as well as the number?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__aljumaily_componentType_tl
\tl_new:N \l__aljumaily_componentNumber_tl

\keys_define:nn {aljumaily/module}{
    assignment  .tl_set:N  = \l__aljumaily_componentNumber_tl,
    assignment  .initial:n = {00},
    assignment  .code:n = {
      \tl_set:Nn \l__aljumaily_componentType_tl{assignment}
    },
    lecture  .tl_set:N  = \l__aljumaily_componentNumber_tl,
    lecture  .initial:n = {00},
    lecture  .code:n = {
      \tl_set:Nn \l__aljumaily_componentType_tl{lecture}
    }
}

\keys_set:nn {aljumaily/module}{assignment=01}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printData}{}{
  \tl_use:N \l__aljumaily_componentType_tl,
  \tl_use:N \l__aljumaily_componentNumber_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\printData, where 00 should be 01
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment

```
assignment  .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l__aljumaily_componentType_tl{assignment} },
```

overrides

```
assignment  .tl_set:N  = \l__aljumaily_componentNumber_tl,
```

You want just `.code:n`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__aljumaily_componentType_tl
\tl_new:N \l__aljumaily_componentNumber_tl

\keys_define:nn {aljumaily/module}
 {
  assignment  .code:n =
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__aljumaily_componentNumber_tl { #1 }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__aljumaily_componentType_tl{assignment}
   },
  assignment  .initial:n = {00},
  lecture  .code:n =
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__aljumaily_componentNumber_tl { #1 }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__aljumaily_componentType_tl{lecture}
   },
  lecture  .initial:n = {00},
}

\keys_set:nn {aljumaily/module}{assignment=01}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printData}{}{
  \tl_use:N \l__aljumaily_componentType_tl,
  \tl_use:N \l__aljumaily_componentNumber_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\printData
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Only for comparison, in `expkv-def` it is pretty straight forward to add another action to an existing key using the `also` prefix. `store` is (almost) equivalent to `.tl_set:N` (though the created `key` will not be `\long`, so no explicit `\par` tokens can be part of its value, you could use the `long` prefix for that, but for a numeric input that doesn't make much sense), and `code` is equivalent to `.code:n` (except for not being `\long` as well without the `long` prefix).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{aljumaily/module}
  {
     store     assignment = \componentNumber
    ,also code assignment = \def\componentType{assignment}
    ,store     lecture = \componentNumber
    ,also code lecture = \def\componentType{lecture}
    ,initial   lecture = 00
  }

\ekvset{aljumaily/module}{assignment=01}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\printData{}
  {\componentType, \componentNumber}

\begin{document}
\printData
\end{document}
```